Table Headers misaligned with columns. All headers above column 1. ASP.NET Core 6
A strange one. I am using ASP.NET Core 6, jQuery and Bootstrap 4. Most of my tables in the application have their headers misaligned with the columns. All the headers seem to be above the first column, see this screenshot here:

The code is as follows:
<table class="table table-bordered table-striped table-hover col-md-12">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            @if ((string)ViewData["Designation"] == "Current")
            {
                <td class="text-center">Registered (NOT designated)</td>
            }
            <td class="text-center">Designation Date</td>
            <td class="text-center">CoP/CoD Document</td>
            <td class="text-center">NSS Finance Customer Code</td>

            @if ((string)ViewData["Designation"] == "Current")
            {
                <td class="text-center">Next Designation Date</td>
                <td class="text-center">First Reminder Sent</td>
                <td class="text-center">Second Reminder Sent</td>
                <td class="text-center">De-designation Notice Sent</td>
            }
    
            <td></td>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
            @if ((string)ViewData["Designation"] == "All" && Model.RenewalDesignations.Any())
            {
                foreach (var designation in Model.RenewalDesignations)
                {
                    <tr>
                        <td class="text-center">@(designation.DesignatedAt.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy"))</td>
                        <td>
                            @if (designation.CoDorCoPDocument != null)
                            {
                                <a asp-controller="Designation" method="get" asp-action="DownloadCoPorCoD" asp-route-id="@designation.Id" class="btn btn-block btn-outline-info">
                                    Download
                                </a>
                            }
                        </td>
                        <td class="text-center">@designation.NssFinanceCustomerCode</td>
                        <td>
                            @if (User.IsInRole("PHSStaff"))
                            {
                                <a asp-controller="Designation" method="get" asp-action="EditDesignation" asp-route-id="@designation.Id" class="btn btn-info btn-block">
                                    Edit
                                </a>
                            }
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                }
            }
    
            @if ((string)ViewData["Designation"] == "All" && !Model.RenewalDesignations.Any())
            {
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="6">
                        No previous designation records
                    </td>
                </tr>
            }
        @if ((string)ViewData["Designation"] == "Current" && (Model.CurrentDesignation != null && !Model.CurrentDesignation.DesignationPending))
 {
         <tr>
             <td class="text-center">
                 @Model.RegisteredNotDesignatedAt.Date.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy")
             </td>
             <td class="text-center">
                 @Model.CurrentDesignation.DesignatedAt.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy")
             </td>
             <td>
                 @if (Model.CurrentDesignation.CoDorCoPDocument != null)
                 {
                     <a asp-controller="Designation" method="get" asp-action="DownloadCoPorCoD" asp-route-id="@Model.CurrentDesignation.Id" class="btn btn-block btn-outline-info">
                         Download
                     </a>
                 }
                 else if (Model.CurrentDesignation.ConditionsOfDesignationId > 0)
                 {
                     <a class="btn btn-primary btn-block" asp-action="ViewCoD" asp-controller="ConditionsOfDesignation" asp-route-id="@Model.CurrentDesignation.ConditionsOfDesignationId" title="Click to open conditions of designation">
                         Conditions of Designation
                     </a>
                 }
             </td>
             <td class="text-center">@Model.CurrentDesignation.NssFinanceCustomerCode</td>
             <td class="text-center">@Html.Raw(Model.CurrentDesignation.NextDesignationDate().Date > Model.CurrentDesignation.DesignatedAt.Date ? Model.CurrentDesignation.NextDesignationDate().ToString("dd/MM/yyyy") : "")</td>
             <td class="text-center">@Html.Raw(Model.CurrentDesignation.FirstRenewalReminderSent ? "Yes" : "No")</td>
             <td class="text-center">@Html.Raw(Model.CurrentDesignation.SecondRenewalReminderSent ? "Yes" : "No")</td>
             <td class="text-center">@Html.Raw(Model.CurrentDesignation.DesignationLapsedSent ? "Yes" : "No")</td>
             <td>
             @if (User.IsInRole("PHSStaff"))
             {
                 <a asp-controller="Designation" method="get" asp-action="Designation" asp-route-id="@Model.VaccinationCentreId" class="btn btn-info btn-block">
                     Edit
                 </a>
             }
             </td>
         </tr>
  }
        </tbody>
    </table>

However I have other tables that are fine!
Any help will be greatly appreciated.

it appears you have conditional column rendering. maybe you need to change if to if else and on the else just do a blank  that way you always have the same number of columns in each row.

Found the issue.
There was a rogue .css file being loaded.
Once found and removed, started to work.
